# Annotation tool for classification experiments

Tags: classification, unsupervised-learning, software-recommendation, experiments, annotation

What tools are available that provide an interface to present text classification results? I need to keep and compare the results of different classification algorithms for unsupervised data. The tool should allow users to give input (like the good match or not) for the presented examples of the test data.

Answer (score 1):

Try [prodigy](https://prodi.gy). An annotation tool powered by active learning.